# How to RSA decrypt in C++ using cipher byte array that is encrypted in C#?

Tags: c#, c++, encryption, rsa, crypto++

I have Encrypted a string, with the public key, in C# using `RSACryptoServiceProvider()` as follows:

```
var rsa = new RSACryptoServiceProvider();
rsa.FromXmlString("xml public string");
var dataToEncrypt = encoder.GetBytes("data to encrypt");
var encryptedByteArray = rsa.Encrypt(dataToEncrypt, false).ToArray(); // false means PKCS#1 v1.5 padding
var length = encryptedByteArray.Count();
var item = 0;
var sb = new StringBuilder();
foreach (var x in encryptedByteArray)
 {
  item++;
  sb.Append(x);
  if (item < length)
     sb.Append(",");
 }

return sb.ToString();
```

As a result of the above I am getting an encrypted string as follows:

```
// It is a sample string, not the real one

122,219,42,174,98,8,221,243,154,194,29,118,166......
```

Which I am then decrypting in C# using the private key as follows:

```
var rsa = new RSACryptoServiceProvider();
var dataArray = data.Split(new char[] { ',' });
byte[] dataByte = new byte[dataArray.Length];
for (int i = 0; i < dataArray.Length; i++)
{
    dataByte[i] = Convert.ToByte(dataArray[i]);
}

rsa.FromXmlString("xml private key");
var decryptedByte = rsa.Decrypt(dataByte, false); // false means PKCS#1 v1.5 padding
return encoder.GetString(decryptedByte);
```

Now, I need to decrypt the encrypted string, in C++ as I do in C#. I have been trying the following code using the Crypto++ library in C++ but I am getting **RSA/EME-PKCS1-v1_5: invalid ciphertext** error.

```
std::string RsaDecryption(string  cipher, const RSA::PrivateKey& key) {

    std::stringstream test(cipher);
    std::string segment;
    std::vector<std::string> seglist;

    while (std::getline(test, segment, ','))
    {
        seglist.push_back(segment);
    }

    int cipherSegSize = seglist.size();
    CryptoPP::byte *cipherByteArray = new CryptoPP::byte[cipherSegSize];

    for (int i = 0; i < cipherSegSize; i++) {
        int tempInt = std::stoi(seglist[i]);
        cipherByteArray[i] = tempInt;
    }


    string recovered;
    try {
        AutoSeededRandomPool rng;
        InvertibleRSAFunction parameters;
        parameters.GenerateRandomWithKeySize(rng, 1024);

        RSA::PrivateKey key(parameters);

        RSAES_PKCS1v15_Decryptor d(key);
              
        StringSource ss(cipherByteArray, cipherSegSize, true,
            new PK_DecryptorFilter(rng, d,
                new StringSink(recovered)
            ) // PK_EncryptorFilter
        ); // StringSource

        cout << " recovered " << recovered << endl;
        
    }
    catch (CryptoPP::Exception& e)
    {
        cerr << "Caught Exception..." << endl;
        cerr << e.what() << endl;
    }

    return recovered;
}
```

just to share, I am getting the private key object from the pem string format as follows:

```
//private key is not real
string privateKeyPem = R"(-----BEGIN RSA PRIVATE KEY-----
MIISQgIBADANBgkqhkiG9w0BAQEFAASCEiwwghIoAgEAAoIEAQDB76wqsKzMcvv9
/aMxbGjn491mscFukj5iMWMHtHYrWFZZUlG5bkVVLQJr6EOIndOTq0qBdLrNog+y
NRLetEfXP1Nw5eaJgXeSA9kK4RfG5LBD74buPc2IczyNKsJQdSGIb0c3lRAumU9O
dkfDMFOCgNuKsr6lp6hvff/zCCC40lfgJIc++gQ2kev9wDRqMH3u9S0UfNzswlGS
wq/kISiKXi2UDL6eOiQ/lpFyWTQ4hH3lqDX5LVkh06cMACUkoN3Sn2EXKCNZZdeB
TN9f8biL4WxTY3koUxXS0dOB9+VtjXLvbijmdb0CUYIwTY8DApnUuV==
-----END RSA PRIVATE KEY-----)";


RSA::PrivateKey GetPrivateKey() {
          ByteQueue queue;
          static string HEADER = "-----BEGIN RSA PRIVATE KEY-----";
          static string FOOTER = "-----END RSA PRIVATE KEY-----";

          size_t pos1 = privateKeyPem.find(HEADER);
          if (pos1 == string::npos) throw runtime_error("PEM header not found");

          size_t pos2 = privateKeyPem.find(FOOTER, pos1 + 1);
          if (pos2 == string::npos) throw runtime_error("PEM footer not found");

          // Start position and length
          pos1 = pos1 + HEADER.length();
          pos2 = pos2 - pos1;

          string keystr = privateKeyPem.substr(pos1, pos2);

          CryptoPP::StringSource ss{ keystr.c_str(), true };

          Base64Decoder decoder;
          decoder.Attach(new Redirector(queue));
          ss.TransferTo(decoder);
          decoder.MessageEnd();


          try {

              RSA::PrivateKey private_key;

              if (queue.IsEmpty()) {
                  cerr << "The queue is empty...";
              }

              private_key.BERDecode(queue);

              AutoSeededRandomPool prng;
              bool valid = private_key.Validate(prng, 3);
              if (!valid) cerr << "RSA private key is not valid" << endl;

              //cout << "N:" << private_key.GetModulus() << endl;
              //cout << "E:" << private_key.GetPublicExponent() << endl;

              return private_key;

          }
          catch (exception& e) {

              printf("Caught exception: %s\n", e.what());
              exit(1);
          }
      }
```

Any help is highly appreciable.

Comment: The error occurs because the key passed to `RsaDecryption()` is not used. Instead, a new key is generated with `GenerateRandomWithKeySize()`. Delete the line `RSA::PrivateKey key(parameters)` (and the two previous lines). Also, your encoding of the ciphertext into a comma-separated string is horribly inefficient. Usually a Base64 encoding is used for something like this (which is also supported by Crypto++).

Comment: Yes, I got it working using the following project https://github.com/iwpz/Cpp-RSA-AES-with-Csharp found on GitHub. Have to made changes to my C# side too. Thank you.